# Why doesn't YASM doesn't recognize the keyword "offset"?

Tags: assembly, nasm, wow64, yasm

I'm trying to compile [Heaven's Gate](http://vxheavens.com/lib/vrg02.html):

```
yasm-1.2.0-win64.exe "Heaven's Gate.asm"
```

with the code below:

```
global main
section .text
main:
    bits 32
        db      9ah ;call 33:in64
        dd      offset in64
        dw      33h
        ;32-bit code continues here

    bits 64
    in64:
        gs mov rax, qword [30h] ;gs not fs
        mov rax, qword [rax+60h]
        mov rax, qword [rax+18h]
        mov rax, qword [rax+30h]
        mov rax, qword [rax+10h]

    bits 32
        retf
```

but YASM tells me:

```
Heaven's Gate.asm:6: error: undefined symbol `offset' (first use)  
Heaven's Gate.asm:6: error:  (Each undefined symbol is reported only once.)
```

Isn't `offset` a keyword? Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**offset** is superfluous in yasm/nasm syntax. Remove them, as the label itself stands for its offset.

Comment: As for why they have offset in an example clearly targeted for yasm, I don't know. There might have been masm syntax support in earlier versions or something.

Comment: Probably, yeah. There was also an error with `dword ptr` and such, and removing `ptr` fixed that too.